# How to apply a masked array to a very large JSON fast

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, performance

### The Data

I am currently working on very large JSON files formated as such

```
{key: [1000+ * arrays of length 241],
 key2: [1000+ * arrays of length 241],
 (...repeat 5-8 times...)}
```

The data is structured in a way that the **n**th element in each key's array belongs to the **n**th entity. Think about it as each key being a descriptor such as 'height' or 'pressure'. And therefore to get an entity's 'height' and 'pressure' you would access the entities index **n** in all the arrays. Therefore all the key's arrays are the same length **Z**

This, as you can imagine, is a pain to work with as a whole. Therefore, whenever I perform any data manipulation I return a masked array of length **Z** populated with 1's and 0's. 1 means the data in that index in every key is to be kept and 0 means it should be omitted)

---

### The Problem

Once all of my data manipulation has been performed I need to apply the masked array to the data to return a copy of the original JSON data but where the length of each key's array **Z** is equal to the number of 1's in the masked array (If the element in the masked array at index n is a 0 then the element in index n will be removed from all of the json key's arrays and vice versa)

---

### My attempt

```
# mask: masked array
# d: data to apply the mask to
 def apply_mask(mask, d):
    keys = d.keys()
    print(keys)
    rem = [] #List of index to remove
    for i in range(len(mask)):
        if mask[i] == 0:
            rem.append(i) #Populate 'rem'

        for k in keys:
            d[k] = [elem for elem in d[k] if not d[k].index(elem) in rem]

    return d
```

This works as intended but takes a while on such large JSON data

---

### Question

I hope everything above was clear and helps you to understand my question:

> Is there a more optimal/quicker way to apply a masked array to data such as this shown above?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be slow because

```
d[k] = [elem for elem in d[k] if not d[k].index(elem) in rem]
```

is completely recreating the inner list every time.

Since you're already modifying `d` in-place, you could just delete the respective elements:

```py
def apply_mask(mask, d):
    for i, keep in enumerate(mask):
        if not keep:
            for key in d:
                del d[key][i - len(mask)]
    return d
```

(Negative indices `i - len(mask)` are being used because positive indices don't work anymore if the list has already changed its length due to previously removed elements.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the high algorithmic complexity of the code. It is possible to design a much faster algorithm.

Let *K* be the number of keys in the dictionary `d` (ie. `len(d)`). Let *Z* be the size of the mask (ie. `len(mask)`), which is also the typical size of the array values in `d` (ie.`len(d[key])` for any `key`).

The algorithmic complexity of the initial code is **`O(Z^3 * K)`**. This is because `rem` is a list and `in rem` is done in linear time and also because `d[k].index(elem)` search `elem` in `d[k]` in linear time too.

The solution proposed by *finefoot* is faster. Indeed, the complexity of his code is **`O(Z^2 * K)`** (because `del` is done in linear time on CPython lists).

However, is is possible to do the computation in linear time: **`O(K * Z)`**. Here is how:

```py
def apply_mask(mask, d):
    for key in d:
        d[key] = [e for i,e in enumerate(d[key]) if mask[i]!=0]
    return d
```

This code should be several order of magnitude faster.

PS: I think the initial algorithm is not correct regarding the description of the problem. Indeed, some items that should be kept can be removed since `rem` is not cleaned between iterations (and so indices are accumulated).